# How to get Auth Token in incognito window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

Title says it all. I am creating a `tab` in `incognito mode`. When tab is loaded I make a call to `chrome.identity.getAuthToken()` but it shows an alert

**chrome.identity API is disabled in incognito mode.**

I have checked the docs :

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity

It is not mentioned anywhere.
 I was thinking of using `chrome.storage.sync` and `chrome.storage.local` but token expiration would make them useless. Is there any workaround this??

Comment: Incognito means anonymity, lack of any means to identify a user by definition, doesn't it?

Comment: Well you are right. But is there any way I can get authToken in incognito window without using chrome.identity. I was thinking of using chrome.storage.sync and chrome.storage.local but token expiration would make them useless.

Comment: I thought my title was misleading so i changed it.

Comment: Incognito mode is there to avoid being identified. So you can't and shouldn't try to do this. Why do you want this token ?

Comment: I need this token to get access to user's drive and spreadsheets

Comment: make the oauth yourself. its possible. but user would need to approve every time as there might not be a place to store the refresh token (but maybe can be stored in background through messaging)